# Anchor a value in a window function when using UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING

Tags: sql, db2

I have some data that looks something like:

```
K1 K2 V1 S1 V2 V3
A  B  C  1  .  .
A  B  D  2  D  F
A  B  D  2  D  Z
A  B  E  3  .  .
A  B  F  4  .  .
A  B  G  5  .  .
A  B  H  6  .  .
A  X  C  1  .  .
A  X  F  4  .  .
```

I'm trying to determine for rows where V2 is not null (represented by `.`) if the value in V3 exists in V1 for any subsequent rows within the partition of K1 & K2.

So in the example, row 3 would be flagged since F exists in row 5, but row 4 would not be flagged since there is no Z.

I started with:

```
SELECT K1, K2, V1, S1, V2, V3,
  SUM(DECODE(V1, V3, 1, 0)) 
    OVER(PARTITION BY K1, K2 ORDER BY S1 RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS F1
FROM table
ORDER BY K1, K2, S1
```

The problem here is that the comparison in the DECODE between V1 and V3 is row by row.  Is there a way to "anchor" the value for V3 to the CURRENT ROW when looking forward in the window function?

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it with plain old SQL?

```
select *
from Table1 as t1
where v2 != '.'
and v3 in (select v1
           from Table1 as t2
           where t2.k1 = t1.k1
           and   t2.k2 = t1.k2
           and   t2.s1 > t1.s1
           )
```

See fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c36c2/1